# Automatic segmentation of periodic structures

Tags: python, matlab, image-segmentation

I will need your expertise in image analysis where I am a novice.
I have RGB images of periodic structures (laminae) which are doublets (light-dark) in horizontal so they are time series. I need to count, segment all these structures to have their width and an interval thanks to the “replicas” in vertical. But there are difficulties obviously, structures may not be clear and not be found on all the width, they are curved, there are changes in the colors and in the widths as shown in these two images on 2.5 cm (the complete image is 4m)

[Coarse structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ITKz.jpg)

[Fine structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ01g.jpg)

So I proceeded in several steps:

1. I created a mask to remove the outlier pixels corresponding to cracks with values close to 0
2. I converted the RGB to Lab to keep only the L* and I enhanced the contrasts with the CLAHE algorithm
3. I removed the areas with the outliers
4. I binarized the image
5. I did the edge detection

So I have problems in step 2, as CLAHE works in windows if the structures are thin they are not well enhanced and so the binarization will then see only one structure.

I then do a line count, because I don’t know how to do a “2D” count. Because of this counting by line, I have the problem when a structure is not present on all the width, and I do not see how to add the “2D” while trying to find the structure on the other lines especially with the curves.
I don’t know if you can help me to solve my problem of detection to see the fine and coarse structures, but also to have a “2D” count which will not be biased by the partial structures in widths and curves. I guess there is an advantage to use the fact that everything happens on the horizontal and that the vertical is only replicas.

I did these calculations on Matlab, but I can do them on Python too. If you have other free software that can help me I am interested.

Comment: Maybe you want `bwlabel`, i.e. to count connected componets and label them?

Comment: This is not an easy problem. Indeed I would never use CLAHE, as it is intended to improve visual perception, not computational analysis. For the same reasons I wouldn’t use Lab here. My first intuition was to average the rows, after aligning them. But it seems to me that you’d need some complex non-linear alignment to match them up, which would not be very robust.

Comment: I think that bwlabel will give me the same result as the edge detection and will not help me.

Yes I also tried a method that tries to align the structures before segmenting/counting them, but the discontinuities and some mixtures will disturb the method that will not be robust as you say.

Answer (score 0):

We have found a solution. It was to detect all the local min and max with "islocalmin" in Matlab, which allowed to make a good counting. Then for the limits between structures it was necessary to make the same method but in first derivative.
Have a nice day